# Is it possible to include a filter inside an ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-change

I have an ng-change that updates a text input based on the text entered into another input - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256174/angularjs-want-to-show-1-x-in-a-text-input-when-the-users-sets-a-value-0

However the value that is being set with ng-change should only be displayed in steps of 0.01. That is, two decimal places. But due to Chrome not 'fixing' floating point rounding errors for display, sometimes the text input shows values like 0.19999999996.

I was thinking the AngularJS number filter could be of use but adding it inside ng-change isn't working for me -

```
ng-change="v1 = 1 - v2 | number:2"
```

Is it possible to get this to work?...or is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$filter` service in your controller:

```
$filter('number')(number, fractionSize)
```

For example:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter',
  function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.v1 = $filter('number')(1 - $scope.v2, 2);
    };
  }
]);
```

And:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="v2" ng-change="change()" />
  <input ng-model="v1" />
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/lUVyAL8nuCPKM66I7J0W?p=preview

**Updated demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/f8UZQY3d4YF4LFd3FvoF?p=preview

Comment: I have both text inputs set to alter each other. Exactly like this - http://jsbin.com/ketowese/3 - As you can see, if you are using Chrome, it displays the floating point rounding error for some values...I changed the ng-change function to call an updateInputs() method in the controller but this led to ng-change firing recursively and both inputs go instantly to 0 and 1. Can you get your example working with two text inputs that work like in the link I posted?